# Suppress beeping sounds that indicate state changes in TDA7492P

Tags: digital-logic, bluetooth

I have a TDA7492P - breakout module(data sheet https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tda7492p.pdf )

[image]

When powering up, connecting and raising the volume, there are beeping sounds to indicate all those states, which I want to turn off, hear https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GLewYUBkL0Fmmy8AA_-RQEDhtdoy_RUo/view?usp=sharing

Is there a way to hack the firmware or otherwise suppress those beeping sounds?

Comment: The beeping must be generated by the Bluetooth module, not the amplifier chip itself.

Comment: Seems like you would have to reprogram the IC. In theory its possible, but unless you have the source, it's likely way beyond your ability.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue.
The thing I am going to do is follow this tutorial:

https://www.instructables.com/CSR-Bluetooth-Module-Programming/

I hope it will solve it.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain in your own words the relevant information given in the link. This way your answer is still useful even if the link dies.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted in the comments above, these sounds are coming from BT module. This one on board looks like CSR8645 or similar CSR-based BT Audio Module. It does makes those sounds by default.

But gladly it's firmware can be tweaked to change this (and a lot of other settings) via SPI interface and a software called "BlueSuite PSTool". You can use cheap FT232 USB adapter but you need a level shifter of some sort, as CSR chips usually use a 1.8V logic.